# c# sorting a List<> using Tuple?

Tags: c#, linq, tuples

I need to sort a List<> of MediaItem objects by publish date...the publish date is not a property of the item.  So my initial intention was to temporarily tack on a publish date property, load em up, sort, and ditch the property.  Someone at my work suggested I use Tuple and sort with LINQ...I've got about this far in my snippet test, filling up the List<>...but I'm not sure how to sort by that date property using LINQ.  I'll keep looking on my end but if anyone's got any help I'd appreciate it.  Thanks.

```
List<Tuple<MediaItem, DateTime>> list = new List<Tuple<MediaItem, DateTime>>();

            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                DateTime date = new DateTime(2011, i, 1);
                MediaItem item = new MediaItem();
                list.Add(new Tuple<MediaItem, DateTime>(item, date));
            }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `OrderBy( )` LINQ operator to perform the sorting; it allows you to pass a function which extracts the element to sort by. Since the second member of the tuple is the date, we order by `Item2`.

```
var result = list.OrderBy( x => x.Item2 ).ToList();
```

You can reverse the ordering in LINQ by using `OrderByDescending()` instead of `OrderBy().

Also, note that you must either materialize the results or iterate over them, as the `OrderBy()` method is lazy by default. The example above materializes a copy of the list.

If you want to sort the list in place (rather than create a new one), you can supply a `Comparison<T>` delegate to the [`Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) method.

```
 list.Sort( (a,b) => a.Item2.CompareTo(b.Item2) );
```

However, you can do even better - if you always want to main the list in sorted order, you can use the [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) class instead ... however you will have to implement a custom `IComparer<Tuple<MediaItem, DateTime>>` in that case. In this case, when you add items they will always be maintained in sorted order.

Answer (score 6):

One way would be to use the [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) method, using a lambda-expression to create the appropriate `Comparison<T>` delegate.

```
// Sorts tuples in chronological order. To use reverse chronological order,
// use t2.Item2.CompareTo(t1.Item2) instead.
list.Sort((t1, t2) => t1.Item2.CompareTo(t2.Item2));
```

This of course assumes that there are no null-references in the list, which there can't be in your example.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Tuple<MediaItem, DateTime>> list = new List<Tuple<MediaItem, DateTime>>();

 for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
 {
      DateTime date = new DateTime(2011, i, 1);
      MediaItem item = new MediaItem();
      list.Add(new Tuple<MediaItem, DateTime>(item, date));
 }

list.Sort((a, b) => a.Item2.CompareTo(b.Item2));

foreach (var element in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```